# Unity why after first unity methods (Awake(), Start(), etc.) call, instantiated prefab values resets?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Method that insantiate prefab and sets its values

```
private void GenerateShopItems(IShopItem[] item)
    {
        ShopData data = ShopData.GetInstance();
        foreach (var i in data.GetPurchasedItems(item))
        {
            GameObject display = Instantiate(ShopItem, this.transform);
            ShopItemBehavior script = display.GetComponent<ShopItemBehavior>();
            script.AddShopItem(i);
        }
    }
```

ShopItemBehavior method that set values

```
public virtual void AddShopItem(IShopItem item)
    {
        Buttons = this.GetComponentsInChildren<Button>();
        if (ShopItem == null)
            ShopItem = item;
        UpdateUI();
    }
```

My values inside ShopItemBehavior class

```
[SerializeField]
    protected const string BoughtText = "sold out";
    protected Button[] Buttons;
    protected IShopItem ShopItem;
```

When my GenerateShopItems() is called all the values sets correctly but after the first Unity method like Start() is called all of the values are reset to null

Comment: Are you doing anything in Start etc in ShopItemBehavior that changes values? If so, move it to Awake. Awake is called immediately after Instantiate, but Start is called after your function ends.

Comment: No, the only method that changes values is AddShopItem. I can't change values in Awake() cuz I'm passing them when I create the object

Comment: Hold up, AddShopItem only changes the value of the member field ShopItem, which ends up assigning a reference to the created instance. AddShopItem is also virtual so if you have overrides depending on IShopItem derivative, look there.

Comment: Use the debugger and see where the values change. Switch any member values to Properties with backing fields and in set{} use a breakpoint. See the callstack to see where the changes happen. If it doesn't give you an answer, let us know. The code you've posted is not enough to glean anything. e.g. you pass interfaces around and have virtual functions, but we can't know what you do on the concrete types, nor can we tell what type ```var i``` is, or what data it holds.